# Is it possible to serialize certain targets in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to serialize certain targets while parallelizing others in GNU make. I do not have an issue so unfortunately there is no code to share. But I can give an example :

Let's say I have a lot of .c source files that I need to compile and only a few assembly source files that need to be assembled. So, I need to speed up the compiling process by adding the `-j8` option however for some reason I need the assembling process to be serial regardless whether I used the `-j8` option or not. I tried to find a way to make `.NOTPARALLEL` work only on specific targets but I was unsuccessful and all the questions, posts, and articles talked about ordering the targets which is not what I am after. So, is it possible in either of the following forms? If it is possible, what is the proper way to do it?

```
c_sources := a.c b.c c.c
c_objs := a.o b.o c.o
#This process needs to be parallelized.
$(c_sources) : $(c_objs)
   @echo 'Command used to compile .c files.'

assembly_sources := d.s e.s f.s
assembly_objs := d.o e.o f.o

#This process needs to be serialized.
$(assembly_sources) : $(assembly_objs)
   @echo 'Command used to assemble assembly files (.s files).'
```

or

```
#This process needs to be parallelized.
%.c : %.o
   @echo 'Command used to compile .c files.'

#This process needs to be serialized.
%.s : %.o
   @echo 'Command used to assemble assembly files (.s files).'
```

Comment: You could split this into two Makefiles, one for the assembly, and one for the C, and use `.NOTPARALELL` in one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to declare a serialization between two specific targets in GNU make, other than creating a dependency relationship between them.  If target A lists target B as a prerequisite then B will be completely built before A.

It may be useful to investigate order-only dependencies.

Or you can use recursion as mentioned in the comment.

Those are your only options.  Some other versions of make provide special targets that can be interspersed within a list of prerequisites to force "serialization points" but GNU make does not provide this facility.

Since you haven't provided us with a concrete example of a problem to solve we can't give you a more specific solution.